# Digital signing halts with the error "SetDllDirectory function in Pyinstaller is not currently supported by Windows UWP applications"

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, advanced-installer

When I try to create a Windows AppX with Advanced Installer at the digital signing stage the program stops saying "The application calls the SetDllDirectory function which is currently not supported by windows UWP applications. A digitally unsigned exe or msi installer works perfectly but the AppX, as not digitally signed, does not run! Is there a work around to this problem? I searched the Pyinstaller docs and also asked a question on the Pyinstaller Google groups. They did not even list my question.

Comment: We (the Advanced Installer team) are investigating this, once we have a solution we'll back with an update.

Answer (score 1):

according to Microsoft the SetDllDirectory function which is used by Pyinstaller is currently no supported by UWP and according to Pyinstaller experts there is no provision to change this in the near future. So right now this is not the way to go. If there is anyone who knows something better now is the time to speak up..